# Why is my test suite not running any of the tests I have?

Tags: javascript, meteor, mocha.js

I have done this:

1. Added practicalmeteor:mocha
2. Created a tests folder in the root.
3. Created a file called `test.js` with

   ```
   describe('Title', function () {
       it('Checks if the title is present', function () {
           // This code will be executed by the test driver when the app is started
           // in the correct mode
           var text = $('p#buttonText').text();

           // click the button
           $('button').click();

           // assert that we see 'You've pressed the button times.'
           expect(text).toEqual("You've pressed the button 1 times.");

       })
   })
   ```

I execute it with:

```
meteor test --driver-package=practicalmeteor:mocha
```

I have created a repo.[code](https://github.com/SanjeethKumarTS/MeteorTest)

But I cant see any tests being run.The browser says 0 tests. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've made substantial edits to your question so that it is now on-topic for this site. Your original question was asking questions that were primarily opinion-based and too broad ("How to get started?") Or that were off-site resource requests ("Are there any tutorials?"). Make sure that the questions you ask have correct grammar, punctuation and formatting and that they are on-topic. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the name of your test file. In other for `practicalmeteor:mocha` to recognize the test files, you need to name them follow this format `*.test[s].*`. This information is mentioned [here](https://atmospherejs.com/practicalmeteor/mocha#app-testing-with-meteor-test), you should read the document more carefully.

Comment: So now i have changed the file name to `title.tests.page.js`.Ran the test again.No changes.

Comment: @umalogic try `title.tests.js`

Comment: Your folder name may be the problem, I change it to `test` and everything works fine

Comment: I am having another issue. `AssertionError: expected 'You\'ve pressed the button 0 times.' to equal 'You\'ve pressed the button 1 times.'` It does not update the reactiveVar.I am doing $('#btn').click() and i can see in the logs on the Event that the reactiveVar is icremented.